# Winforms: Using Activator.CreateInstance to Create System.Drawing.Image from Resource

Tags: c#, winforms, createinstance

How can I use, if possible,

```
Activator.CreateInstance("MyExeName", "Resources.Image1")
```

to create a background image that will be associated with a button? `Image1` is the image defined in the resources named `"Image1"`.

```
var handle = Activator.CreateInstance("TestApp", "Resources.Image1");
var backgroundImage = handle.Unwrap() as System.Drawing.Image;
```

I did not see anything like this in stackoverflow. What am I missing?

Thanks for looking and any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? What is the goal here? sounds like you want to extract an image from the app resources and assign it to a button? then why use reflection? why not get the resource and extract it then finally intercept it as an image and assign it to the button image/background?

Comment: I am looking for a way to get resources based on a name that is derived from the button name. I want to avoid passing in each individual resource name through a parameter list or worse yet having a long list  of repetitive resource assignments. In other words, I want to loop through a list of buttons deriving the resources for assignments from the button name in the list. Sorry if this does not make sense. I can edit the original post if needed to clarify with code.

Comment: @Buck Reflection isn't required. Images are stored as byte streams, so you can read the bytes out into a new `Image` instance. It simply takes a string resource name, which you can build dynamically as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can derive the name of the resource you want, then use this:

```
using System.Resources;

public static Image GetImage(String ImageName)
{
    Image retImage = null;
    Object o = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(ImageName);
    if (o != null && (o is Image))
    {
        Image img = (Image)((Image)o).Clone();  //necessary to prevent premature disposal
        retImage = img;
    }
    return retImage;
}
```

Here's the MSDN on [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and there are many SO questions relating to its use.